# How can I remove unwanted characters from a words list and put them cleared in another list using Python?

Tags: python, regex, list, search

I'm new in Python and working on a lexicon database. 
I have three lists : the first one contains several words from the database I want to test, the second one contains prefixes and the third one contains suffixes. 
I need to make another list (called "radicals") that would contain the words from the first list that matched with the two other lists but with their prefixes or suffixes removed.

I'm sure I'm not using the right method here but here's my code :

```
#coding UTF-8
import re 
from re import search 


words = ["flore", "fleur", "fleuriste", "remaniement", "remanier", "manier", "maniable", "désaimer", "aimer", "aimant", "mêler", "emmêler", "désemmêler"]
radicals = []
i = 0
motifp = "^[re|em|dés]"
motifs = "[iste|ment|er|ant]$"

while i < len(words) : 
    if re.search(motifs, words[i]) : 
        del(motifp, words[i])
        del(motifs, words[i])
        radicals.append(words[i])
    i = i + 1
print(radicals)
```

It returns the following error :

```
['fleur']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alice\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PythonApplication4\PythonApplication4\PythonApplication4.py", line 14, in <module>
    del(motifp, words[i])
NameError: name 'motifp' is not defined
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I could really use your help...
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Does your suffixes and prefixes always located in the start and end of the word?

Comment: When you run del(...) you want to delete from words array ? because now it's deleting the whole motifs and motifp variable, that's why the crash.

Comment: Yes, prefix always at the beginning and suffix always at the end of the word.

Comment: @farbiondriven I actually don't, del() might be a bad solution since I basically just want to ignore prefixes and suffixes from the words list and put all words that contain at least one in the radicals list without their prefix or suffix... if it was possible I would do something like this : words[i] = words[i] - motifp

Comment: Your regex is wrong, `[re|em|dés]` means a single character from `r`,`e`,`|`,`m`,`d`,`é`,`s`. You probably mean `(re|em|dés)` or `(?:re|em|dés])`

Comment: @SebastianProske Yess, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to iterate over each word and remove any defined prefix or suffix. That's it. And since some radicals will be the same, e.g., for fleur and fleuriste, use a `set`.

```
import re 

words = ["flore", "fleur", "fleuriste", "remaniement", "remanier", "manier", "maniable", "désaimer", "aimer", "aimant", "mêler", "emmêler", "désemmêler"]
radicals = set()
motifp = "^(re|em|dés)"
motifs = "(iste|ment|er|ant)$"

for word in words:
    word = re.sub(motifp, '', word)
    word = re.sub(motifs, '', word)
    radicals.add(word)
print(radicals)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly ! 
Although if I want to keep the radicals from fleur and fleuriste even if they're the same, what should I do ?

Comment: @AlicePhoenix In that case, `radicals` should be a list and you simply do `radicals.append(word)`.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, just tested with a list and it's perfect !